# How to deal with large exponents b of exponential-functions, e^b?

Tags: programming-practices

I am working on a little project (in a very "low Level" language with single-precision 32-bit float that nearly has no functionality apart from basic conditions and loops) and at one point I have to solve a linear system of equations (4x4 or sometimes 5x5). This is not the problem, I use the GAUSSian algorithm with pivoting. To increase the speed of calculation, it is also possible to use a straight-forward coded explicit solution of the 4x4 system (e.g. gained from Matlabs symbolic toolbox.)

The problem I have to deal with is now that sometimes in my system of equations there can occur exponential functions *e*<sup>*b*</sup> with quite high exponents, lets say *b*>10000 ... the thing is that these huge values vanish when the system is solved.
The next thing is that *b* are no integer values but some decimal things ...

Is there a way for a quick kind of "factorization" of for example *e*<sup>13421.1234</sup>? Or what can I do to make my equation-system solvable?

**Edit: example-set of equations**

```
x_i = 0 ... >1000               = values from Measurement, i.e. time in days]
y_i = 0, 1e-6 ... 1e-4          = values from Measurement, i.e. creep-strain]
b_i = 1/1, 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000  = constants
a_i = Regression-Parameters to be estimated

(1): ( a_1*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_1+b_1)} +
       a_2*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_2+b_1)} +
       a_3*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_3+b_1)} +
       a_4*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_4+b_1)} ) = ( sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i*e^{x_i*b_1} )

(2): ( a_1*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_1+b_2)} +
       a_2*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_2+b_2)} +
       a_3*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_3+b_2)} +
       a_4*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_4+b_2)} ) = ( sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i*e^{x_i*b_2} )

(3): ( a_1*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_1+b_3)} +
       a_2*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_2+b_3)} +
       a_3*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_3+b_3)} +
       a_4*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_4+b_3)} ) = ( sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i*e^{x_i*b_3} )

(4): ( a_1*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_1+b_4)} +
       a_2*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_2+b_4)} +
       a_3*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_3+b_4)} +
       a_4*sum_{i=1}^{k}*e^{x_i*(b_4+b_4)} ) = ( sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i*e^{x_i*b_4} )
```

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering Stack Exchange doesn't do coding help...](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: Have you searched for algorithms for exponentiation?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser, yes I did but was not sure if that works also for exponents which are no integers

Comment: @DocBrown The numbers from e^b come from my input data. I have a set of $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns. This system results if I do the linear regression-algorithm. But I am not sure if it is solveable if the input-values are large scaled.

Comment: looks like the factor 1/k is superfluous?

Comment: ah, sorry, that was a mistake - I'll correct it

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are using floats. They are notorious for rounding issues and aren't used for anything requiring precision in the calculations. Most numbers can only represent 6 significant digits but there are some numbers that can represent as many as 9 significant digits. Thus, if you had a 32 bit float number 1,000,000,000,000.0 and add 1.0 to it then  it's still going to be 1,000,000,000,000.0 and NOT 1,000,000,000,001.0. double is capable of representing more significant digits but even it has a max. So if your b's are vastly different even double won't help.

Answer (score 2):

So these are four or five linear equations (in four or five unknowns) with your $e^b$'s as coefficients, is that right?

Then I'd think you can **divide** all the terms of an equation by any constant you like. And each equation has four or five $e^{b_i},i=1...4or5$ coefficients. So just look for the smallest $b_i$ (in each equation separately) and **subtract** it out from each, i.e., $b_i-->b_i-b_{min}$ in that equation. Do that separately for each equation, and it should leave the overall solution unchanged.

Since you say "these huge values vanish when the system is solved", that implies that the $b_max-b_min$'s can never be very large. So when you subtract out the $b_min$'s, that should leave the remaining $e^{b_i-b_min}$'s tractable.

Comment: You're right. This are $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns with $e^b$ as coefficients. I'll add an example of my equation-system in the original question.

Comment: I think this answer is a pointer into the right direction. I guess it may be better, however, to look for the biggest exponent, not for the smallest.

Comment: Thats true, I also thought about it before; but my problem is that the equation-system is a kind of very badly scaled so that there occur rather big coefficients besides rather small ones.

Comment: @Questionmarkengineer Okay, so those a_i's are the unknowns. Your Eq(4) looks particularly bad with b_1+b_4=1.001 and b_4+b_4=0.002 multiplying the x_i's, which could lead to exponents with max-min pretty large. You might want to try posting your question in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ where it may be more on-topic (and where mathjax works:)

Comment: @Questionmarkengineer But with "rather big coefficients besides rather small ones" (your remark in preceding comment, agreeing with my observation about Eq.4), how does your original post remark that "these huge values vanish when the system is solved" work??? You're essentially inverting a matrix with some **very big** elements and some very small ones.  Offhand, I'm not seeing how your "huge values vanish".

Comment: @JohnForkosh That was a bad "guess" by myself, because I know that the resulting coefficients a_i are always somewhere around 1e5, and therefor I guessed that the exponents might cancel out ... (I forgot to mention that the exponents of e^(...) are always negative; but that doesn't change anything). - The given system has not yet been solved because of the problem with the exponents; I got the results from matlab by performing lsqnonlin() though the problem initially is - in my opinion - a linear regression ...

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519989/879997) has some C code for implementing `pow` and `exp`.

If you want to implement it yourself, recall that `exp(a + b) = exp(a) + exp(b)` (mathematically, at least). If you have a floating point number, you can treat it as the sum of an integer part and a decimal part, `x = n + d`. `exp(n)` can be computed with repeated multiplication, and then you just have to find `exp(d)`.

With a Taylor series around 0 (technically a Maclaurin series (: ), that can be computed as `d + (d^2 / 2) + (d^3 / 6) + ... + (d^k / k!)`. Since those powers are all integers, they can be computed with repeated multiplication.

Take the results from the two parts above, multiply them, and you have `exp(x)`.

I don't totally like the idea of repeatedly multiplying `e`, but you could implement base 2 exponentiation and compute `exp(x) = 2^(x / log_2(e))`. Integer powers of 2 can be computed with bitshifting, but then the Taylor series for the decimal part would be off. I'm not sure which would be more accurate overall.

Keep in mind that there are potential numerical analysis issues here, especially with negative numbers. I don't think there would be any problems, but I would recommend thorough testing of your algorithm before using it in production. Specific things to watch out for are how far you want to take the Taylor series, negative bases and exponents, and combinations of very small and very large values.